# Xcode 6.2 setting iCloud Capabilities error

Tags: ios, xcode6, icloud, entitlements, app-id

I'm going to update a published app, compiling it using Xcode 6.2 and iOS8 sdk as requested.
I'm trying to set up iCloud entitlements but everytime i click on "*Fix issue*" button to "*Add the iCloud containers to your App ID*" I got this error:
[image]

Any suggestion?